# Videos not playing on Android in an offline state when using appcache

Tags: android, html, video, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I am having an issue with trying to cache and play videos in an offline state on an Android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab) using the appcache manifest file.   My file looks like this (below).  It worked fine on iOS.  Android will pull in the stylesheet and the image when it is launched offline, but the video will not play.  Anyone out there have a working demo online? I've also tried adding an .htaccess file to see if that would help, but it didn't.

.htaccess file:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/m4v .mp4
```

manifest file

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
*

CACHE:
main.js
index.html
styles.css
jquery-1.11.1.min.js
video1.mp4
video1.m4v

citypark_icon.png
```

html file

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
    <head>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <title>video cache test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <div id="status"></div>
        <div>
            <video id="1" width="320" height="240" controls>
                 <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
                 <source src="video1.m4v" type="video/mp4" >
            </video>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: offline video and audio seems to be supported offline on desktop chrome and safari but not on mobile chrome

Comment: @sean did you ever get this to work?

Comment: I gave this up shortly after the post.  I never got it to work properly.